# How do I exit from the do-while loop even if the break is declared in the if statement?

Tags: c

How do I exit from the do-while loop even if the break is declared in the if statement?

```c
struct node * sort(struct node * head, int data) {
  struct node * newp = (struct node * ) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  newp -> data = data;
  newp -> link = NULL;
  int key = data;
  struct node * temp = head;
  if (head == NULL || key < temp -> data) {
    newp -> link = temp;
    head = newp;
    return head;
  } else {
    do {
      if (temp -> link -> data > key) {
        //I have declared break here but according to the rule inner loop 
        // must break why the do while loop is also exiting.
        break;
      }
      temp = temp -> link;
    } while (temp -> link != NULL);
    newp -> link = temp -> link;
    temp -> link = newp;

    return head;
  }

}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear what you are asking. Are you trying to figure out why the `break` statement exits your `do/while` loop? Your question appears to be asking about a nested loop but there is only 1 loop in your program.

Comment: `if` statements are not loops. `while`, `do while` and `for` are. Needless is to say you have no inner loops there.

Comment: You're talking about inner loops, but I do not see any nested loops (the only loop is the `do...while` loop, and `break` exits from it). `if` is not considered a loop and thus `break` will not "break" from it.

Comment: if `break` would only break out of `if`, a conditional break would not be possible.

Answer (score 1):

An `if` statement is not a loop. Loop statements, called iteration statements in the C standard, are `while`, `do`, and `for` statements.

A `break` exits the innermost `switch`, `while`, `do`, or `for` statement containing it. (A `switch` statement is not an iteration statement, but `break` will exit it.)